# Django: Where should I put queries about User which is in relation with other models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-managers

I am writing a Django app which define groups of user. A user can be part of many groups.

I want to be able to retrieve, from a list of groups, users which are members of at least one of those groups and with no duplicate.

So i wrote a query to accomplish that. That method will take a list of group_id and simply returns a list of users.
My question is: where is the best place to put that method?

I was thinking to create a custom manager for my Group model. But it don't seems logical as my method will return to me a list of Users.

According to the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/

Manager of a model should contains queries about that model.

After some research, I've seen that is not advised to extends the django.auth.models.User manager (at least in my case).

For the moment, i will just put my method in a 'service.py' file, but I was wondering if there is not a more elegant way to accomplish what i am trying to do.

Thanks by advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a `ManyToManyField` relation from `User` to `Group`, like the following?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')
```

I don't think there's a reason to write a method to achieve this, it's just a one-line call to `filter`:

```
User.objects.filter(groups__in=group_ids)
```

If you must make it a method, I don't think there's an "official" place to put this. The `User` manager would probably be closest, but as you say, adding a custom manager to `User` is a pain. Django apps are just python code, and aren't very prescriptive about where non-framework methods go, so put it where it makes sense for your code/team.

Note that [Django already provides all of this functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization), and even names the model `Group`, so it seems like you're reinventing the wheel writing your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, I already used User Groups for permission. My question was more about conception and where put that kind of code. My app is a newsletter and i wanted to be able to target very specific users with a newsletter campaign. But you're right, i totally can manage it with Django groups! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py you can use the below function and call it in your view:

```
def get_groups_users(*groups):
    users = User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=list(groups))
    return list(set(users))
```